# Using integer variable in pulp as binary

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pulp

I have optimization problems with many integer variables x1,x2,x3... and I set many constraints on them and everything is fine. But now I have  constraints that  involve expression that  treats them as binaries. For example:

(if x1 > 0 then 1 else 0)*someconst_1 + (if x2 > 0 then 1 else 0)*someconst_2 >= 0

Is there any alternative in pulp to code  this constraint without declaring many binary variables - one  for each  integer variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given information, there isn't a short way. Because each one will be dependent on integer variables. But if these are on equation levels, disjunctive and conjunctive normal forms can be useful for you.